# Removing custom widget area WordPress 4.4

Tags: widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I know it is a very simple thing but I just cannot figure it out.

I always used to define widget areas and sidebar in source code, however this time I have used the UI option from `Appearance > Widgets` to create a widget area.

Now I need to remove, however I cannot find how to do it, because there is nothing in the source code.

Comment: How can one create *widgets-areas* with the core UI? My guess is that this is theme/plugin specific UI feature.

Comment: I have a brand new 4.4 install and I can't locate a "UI Option" to create widget areas, and I am having a bit of trouble imagining how that would work without complicity from the theme.

Comment: As far as I know the commercial theme Avada has such a feature to add custom widget areas but it is nothing provided by WP Core.

Comment: The widget areas in my theme are set up inside the theme's `functions.php` for placing the drag and drop widget panel in the dashboard and in the relevant bar widget area - for which widgets to show when. It had comments like: `// Enable custom class only if the left sidebar is active.` where `left` could be whichever sidebar.

Comment: It also had a large section headed `Register sidebars and widgetized areas.` which is where you set up arrays to fill the dashboard panels. You could create page parts (like `my-sidebar.php` for example) which had code in them to control which widgets were shown when. If a widget had nothing in it it simply did not appear.

Comment: What theme do you have installed? What widget related plugins?